# Azure Function App with CosmosDB input binding - can I get data without using Urifactory.CreateDocumentURI()?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-function-app

I am new to Azure. I tried to create Cosmos DB Input Binding in Visual Studio using .NET Core.

**Firstly**, I created data in my Cosmos DB:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "myName",
    "full_name": "My full name"
}
```

**Secondly**, I modified local.settings.json:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    },
    /* WARNING! Remember to add same ConnectionString in Azure Portal 
       (App Function -> Configuration) */
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "CosmosDBConnectionString": "AccountEndpoint=my_connection_string"
    }
}
```

**Thirdly**, I added my code:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    [CosmosDB(
        "BindingDB",
        "names", 
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnectionString")] DocumentClient documentClient,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogWarning(">>> Function started! <<<");
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    string partitionKey = data?.name ?? "";
    string id = data?.id ?? "";

    Document doc = await documentClient.ReadDocumentAsync(
        UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("BindingDB", "names", id),
        new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) 
    });

    var fullName = doc.GetPropertyValue<string>("full_name") ?? "";
    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName) ? 
        "Something went wrong!" : 
        $"Hello, {fullName}.";

    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

**Lastly**, I send POST request with body:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "myName"
}
```

**It works!** But I have a question:

**Question** - I hardcoded my database and collection names in code twice! I like clean code. Can I somehow get my data without using `UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri()`?

The documentation is not clear, and some resources in internet are outdated. That's why I ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_ReadDocumentAsync_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) alternate method (without creating URI):

```
//This reads a document record from a database & collection where
// - sample_database is the ID of the database
// - sample_collection is the ID of the collection
// - document_id is the ID of the document resource
// - partition_key is the Partition Key value, needed for Cosmos DB
var docLink = "dbs/sample_database/colls/sample_collection/docs/document_id";
var parKey = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("partition_key") };
Customer customer = await client.ReadDocumentAsync<Customer>(docLink, parKey);
```

*Alternatively*, you can read the config setting once in a static variable and use it throughout your Function App.

Comment: **Note:** use `using RequestOptions = Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions;` and `using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;` for defining `var parKey`!